# How to construct a list from a single output

Tags: list-manipulation

Sorry if I didn't make it clear in the title but is there a way to construct a list from

```
montecarlo = If[Norm[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 1}]] < 1, 1, 0]
```

for an *n* number of times, like:

```
{0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define your `montecarlo` using [`SetDelayed (:=)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) instead of [`Set (=)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) you can simply use `Table[montecarlo, n]` to generate a list `n` random numbers:

```
ClearAll[montecarlo]
montecarlo := If[Norm[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 1}]] < 1, 1, 0]

n = 10;
SeedRandom[1]
Table[montecarlo, n]
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}

A faster alternative is to generate a list of length `n` and to process it:

```
SeedRandom[1]
1 - UnitStep[Norm /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2, 1}] - 1]
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}